# Requesting caches for memory in c and c++

Tags: c++, c, caching

I have a program involving a large array of allocated entities. I have not decided if they will be continuous in memory or be in a more linked list format.

As often as possible these entities need to be updated based on a chunk of memory I am going to call the common variables.

In this way the main code of the project looks like the following

```
for (entity in entities) {
 //Use common variables to update this entity
}
```

It would be really nice if I could somehow influence the hardware to store the global variables on the fastest cache whenever possible so that it can be consistently read and written frequently.

In c or c++ is there a at all a way to influence the memory heiarchy? Even if there isnt a definitive way to do this is there a way to increase the probability that the common variables will be inserted, and stay in, the cache?

How would my technique need to change if my entities were a linked list rather than a continuous chunk of memory?

BTW I am not exactly sure how big each entity will be nor the common variables. If I had to guess I would assume the common variables would be somewhere around 1.2 kbytes and each entity would be around .72kbytes but that could grow or shrink in the final program

Comment: Have you measured that this is a bottle-neck? If not then don't fall into the trap of premature optimization. Instead concentrate on writing good and nice code that is easy to read and maintain. Then if the performance isn't up to the requirements (and remember that good enough usually *is* good enough) then measure, profile and benchmark to find the hot-spots and bottle-necks, and concentrate on those. Providing good documentation and commentary, since optimizations tends to make code hard to read and understand.

Comment: Hardware caching behavior is not typically directly modifiable by the application-programmer; your path towards better performance will be to modify the patterns by which your code accesses memory.  If you're worried about minimizing cache misses, you will probably want to avoid linked lists and use arrays instead -- anything where you can increase the locality of subsequent memory accesses will improve cache performance.  (But be sure to measure as you go, otherwise you might end up spending a lot of time "optimizing" the performance of code that turns out not to really matter very much)

Comment: "... store the global variables ..." - in general, using global variables is a bad idea. They increase coupling between components and needing/using globals is generally a sign of bad design.

Comment: How would you recommend I store information like the velocity and position of each finger, the geometry of the frame and bounds, current time information, and global animation parameters needed for all entries?

Answer (score 0):

> In c or c++ is there a at all a way to influence the memory heiarchy?

If you are using GCC/CLANG, there is a `__builtin_prefetch()`. If you are not, you can try `_mm_prefetch()` or direct assembly code. For x86 architectures there is a `PREFETCHx` instruction. Here is an example:

```
void prefetch(void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("prefetcht0 %[p]" : : [p] "m" (*(char *)p));
}
```

Have a look at [Compiler Explorer.](https://godbolt.org/g/T87dy4)

> How would my technique need to change if my entities were a linked list rather than a continuous chunk of memory?

You can try to use the prefetch technique to speedup linked list traversal, but there are some caveats as usual:

1. Prefetch is a asynchronous CPU instruction, i.e. we have to prefetch next or next after next chunk and then start to process the current memory chunk. So once we done with the current chunk, the next chunk will be in CPUs cache.
2. Due to item 1, there is an unspecified and platform dependent delay between the `PREFETCHx` instruction issued and the data actually in the cache. Basically this means that some your computers prefetching next memory chunk speeds up the process 2 times, while on the other computers it gives nothing or even degrade the performance.
3. Prefetch works on cache lines and for x86 architectures it is 64 bytes. If the memory chunk is greater that the cache line, we should consider prefetching also the `memory chunk + CACHE_LINE_SIZE` address.

Overall, modern CPUs have hardware prefetchers, predictors, can execute the code speculatively etc etc. So this manual prefetch technique could juice some performance, but I am afraid that it could also be just a waste of time. Consider this technique as a last resort optimization, when all other techniques (like better algorithm, better memory layout etc) are already done.